# Axios delete in react not working and returning network error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I have used axios library to call a delete endpoint implemented with Flask.
While I am able to invoke it with a curl request. The react code returns a network error.

Flask API implementation

```
@app.route('/environment/<environment_name>/tag/<tag>/', methods=['DELETE'])
def deleteEnvironmentTag(environment_name, tag):
    return deleteEnvTag(environment_name, tag)
```

Also in the API CORS support is enabled

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

React code returning Network Error

```
  export async function deleteTag(environment_name, tag) {
    try {
      const environment_name_encoded = encodeURIComponent(environment_name);
      const tag_encoded = encodeURIComponent(tag);
      const complete_endpoint = `${api_endpoint}/environment/${environment_name_encoded}/tag/${tag_encoded}`;
        
      await axios.delete(complete_endpoint);
      console.log(`Deleting environment ${environment_name} tag ${tag} successful`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error deleting environment ${environment_name} tag ${tag}: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
```

When I curl from terminal I api endpoint invocation works fine but it fails to be invoked by react.

`curl --location --request DELETE 'http://10.27.101.152:7070/environment/ancient-MNO/tag/MNO'`

`Successfully deleted tags for ancient-MNO`**`%`**

Error details

```
code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
: 
adapter
: 
(2) ['xhr', 'http']
data
: 
undefined
env
: 
{FormData: ƒ, Blob: ƒ}
headers
: 
AxiosHeaders
Accept
: 
"application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type
: 
null
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
: 
(...)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
maxBodyLength
: 
-1
maxContentLength
: 
-1
method
: 
"delete"
timeout
: 
0
transformRequest
: 
[ƒ]
transformResponse
: 
[ƒ]
transitional
: 
{silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}
url
: 
"http://localhost:7070/environment/ancient-MNO/tag/FP2"
validateStatus
: 
ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName
: 
"XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName
: 
"X-XSRF-TOKEN"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"Network Error"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44165:14)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
```

Comment: By any chance, is it ```CORS``` error ? can you screenshot the error for us ?

Comment: I pasted the error details here

Comment: that's not how you paste error, can you just give us the screenshot ?

Comment: network error in axios usually occurs when the url is not correct or incomplete, maybe it'll help